# com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker ----- HTMLWorker.Parse error in Java

Tags: java, itext

I have a problem with HTMLWorker.Parse From com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.
When I excecute the code giving exception "java.io.IOException: Expected > for tag: <{1}/> near line       1, column 36078".Here is the code:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker;
public class MReport{
HTMLWorker htmlParser = new HTMLWorker(document);
while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
linecount=linecount+1;
recourdcount++;
htmlString.append(nextLine);
if(linecount!=NoOfLinesToWrite){
htmlString.append("\n");
}
}
if (nextLine == null) {
InputStream in=new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlString.toString().getBytes());
BufferedReader readerBody_circle=new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(in));
sb_result.append(utility.writeBody( readerBody_circle,null,dto_circle));
sb_result.append(utility.writeFooter(footer_circle, null));
if(dto_circle.getFormat().equalsIgnoreCase("P")){
StringReader streader=new StringReader(sb_result.toString());
htmlParser.parse(streader); //giving expextion at this line
document.close();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please add your `htmlString` to your question.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like your `htmlString` contains "<{1}/>" which is invalid HTML. That been said, the `HTMLWorker` supports only a very limited subset of HTML Furthermore, it was deprecated many years ago.

Comment: reader present in the line, while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) contains data retrieved from database which is present into .csv file.